# Auto Complete TextField 'map' was called on null Flutter

Tags: flutter, autocomplete

I'm trying to create a search field that searches between objects (by their 'name').

```dart
  List<SearchRecipeEntity> recipeEntitySuggest = [];
  List<SearchRecipeEntity> recipemap= new List<SearchRecipeEntity>();


 @override
  void initState() {
   ...
            for (var recipe in data['records']) {
              recipeEntitySuggest.add(
                  SearchRecipeEntity(id: recipe['id'], name: recipe['name']));
            }
            recipemap= recipeEntitySuggest
                .map<SearchRecipeEntity>((entry) =>
                    SearchRecipeEntity(id: entry.id, name: entry.name))
                .toList();
            setState(() {});
     ...
  }

 Widget _buildIngredientsAutocompleteTextField() {
    return AutoCompleteTextField<SearchRecipeEntity>(
      itemBuilder: (context, item) {
        return row(item);
      },
      itemFilter: (item, query) {
        return item.name.startsWith(query);
      },
      itemSorter: (a, b) {
        return a.name.compareTo(b.name);
      },
      focusNode: myFocusNode,
      key: searchRecipeKey,
      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
      decoration: InputDecoration(
          hintText: "חיפוש מתכון",
          icon: Icon(
            Icons.search,
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
          hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
      suggestions: recipemap,
      clearOnSubmit: false,
      submitOnSuggestionTap: true,
      itemSubmitted: (item) => setState(() {
        print("clicked on " + item.name + " id number " + item.name);
        var route = new MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (BuildContext context) => new RecipePage(
                  title: item.name,
                  id: item.id,
                ));
        Navigator.of(context).push(route);
      }),
    );
  }
```

this is the Error when something is typed to the search field

```
The method 'map' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: map<Row>(Closure: (SearchRecipeEntity) => Row)
```

I'm not fully understand the map issue probably has something to do with the 'recipemap' or maybe the Row Widget? Any suggestions?

Comment: you are sure that `data['records']` had some data inside?

Comment: @ViniciosWentz yes Im sure